# Why do I can not start Kafka as a Java agent

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, javaagents, jmx-exporter

I have problem with JMX when start Kafka as Java agent with this compose file:

```
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    volumes:
      - ./jmx-exporter:/usr/share/jmx_exporter
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@broker:29093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,CONTROLLER://broker:29093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
      CLUSTER_ID: 'MkU3OEVBNTcwNTJENDM2Qk'
      EXTRA_ARGS:
        -javaagent:/usr/share/jmx-exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.20.0.jar=1234:/usr/share/jmx-exporter/zookeeper.yml
        -javaagent:/usr/share/jmx-exporter/jolokia-jvm-1.7.1.jar=port=1235,host=*
        -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/jmx-exporter/exporter_debug_logging.properties
```

And my issue is:

```
broker                        | Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /usr/share/jmx-exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.20.0.jar
broker                        | Error occurred during initialization of VM
broker                        | agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I have search on internet a lot but I can find a solution for my issue

Comment: The error seems to suggest your JAR file is corrupted. Try downloading again (and not using **zookeeper** YAML file for Kafka)

Comment: I have re-download from official release but I doesn't work. Still this error

Comment: Maybe you have some firewall or antivirus modifying the download? I'll point out that Strimzi has JMX exporter built in, and so you could use Docker Desktop kubernetes cluster to run that instead of using compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. maybe the following points will help you:

1. First of all, check that your jars inside of a container are executable. If not, fix it with 'chmod +x'.
2. Check also who owns jars. Your container uses (probably) 'appuser'-user by default and doesn't have permission to execute jars. If so, you need to change the owner of jars to appuser.